How to hide or encrypt api calls from Network tab?
When I communicate with my server using API calls from client side. I saw my api address completly visible in the network tab. And my api data also visible in the payload. So any one can communicate with my server using this API. It's makeing security issue in my project.
I want to completly hide my api call from the network tab. How can I do this? Or how can I encrypt my payload and response data?
Thanks a lot.

"It's makeing security issue in my project." - How so?  You're likely approaching the problem the wrong way here.  If the client shouldn't be able to access the API then why is the code accessing it in the first place?  What's the actual problem?

Using Next.js with Server-Side Rendering (SSR) can enhance security by keeping sensitive operations on the server side rather than exposing them to the client.

If you want any calls to be secure and hidden, you're going to need some sort of serverside code that you control acting as middleware so that your react app will only call those endpoints - then your backend can securely make the API calls that you want to keep hidden

You need to adjust your thinking here. A browser runs on a machine that your user fully controls. Anything the browser sees/does can be inspected, manipulated and controlled by your users. This includes all Javascript code and network requests. everything is open.
Security in Web Applications does not mean 'hiding' stuff. You can do this a little but anything you do can be defeated. Build your security around the fact that users can do this. It needs to not matter.
If a user seeing an API endpoint is a security risk, then your API is broken. Fix it there.

React is ruining the internet for this reason - people are being taught how to use it without learning proper security. I had a junior dev telling me his secret key for a front end app was "safe" because it was stored in an environment variable. Didn't believe my warning that the compile process was writing it to public code until I grabbed his API key by viewing source and searching the key structure with a regex in front of him.

@jmcgriz If it makes you feel any better, I've been a web developer for 20 years, and 20 years ago there were also plenty of people who were still learning about the security model of browsers.
